# Retuning values using recursion in Scheme

Tags: for-loop, recursion, scheme

I want to make for-loop using recursion in scheme.

I wrote recursion code which stops at 2, but it doesn't return a

number.

If I write the code in JAVA,

It should be look like this.

```
 global varialbe int i;

public int decreasingNumber( int n)
{
 if (n == 2) 
  return -1
 else 
 {
  i = n
  return decreasingNumber(n - 1)
 }
}
```

So that I can get changed i, until function reaches 2.

In scheme, I tried

```
(define (IT n)
  (let ((i n ))

(if (= i 2) "done"


  (IT(- n 1))

   )    
  )
 )
```

Scheme doesn't let this code work

```
(+ i 0)
```

before the recursion.

Comment: Your java code is incorrect - first, you should not depend on an external attribute for updating the state of a recursion. Second, it'll always return -1, because you're not doing anything with the value returned by the recursion. What was the expected result, say, if I call `decreasingNumber(10)` ?

Comment: you can use `set!` to alter a top-level variable, which must first be defined with `define`. -- using mutable global variables for such basic tasks is contrary to the spirit of Scheme. if something can be achieved without this, it usually should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a global variable in Java and a local in Scheme. If you were to do this:

```java
public static int decreasingNumber(int n) {
    if (n == 2) {
        return -1;
    } else { 
        int i = n; // dead code
        return decreasingNumber(n - 1);
    }
}

int minusOne = decreasingNumber(10);
System.out.println(i + 0); // compilation error!!! i doesn't exist
```

So you see why `i` wouldn't exist after calling `decreasibngNumber`?
If you want `IT` do return something else than the string "done" you shoudl perhaps replace "done" with whatever you want it to return.. eg.

```scm
(define (count-down-to-two n)
  (if (= n 2)
      -1                             ; return -1 (why?)
      (count-down-to-two (- n 1))))  ; return the result of this recursion
```

However seeing this can be simplified makes me want to write this instead:

```scm
; simplified version
(define (count-down-to-two n)
  -1)
```

Setting global variables (or lexical when closer) can be done with `set!`:

```scm
(set! i n) ; like i = n in java
```

Often you can get away by just make the procedure return whateveryou need and make your code functional and easier to test. Go through a book or tutorial to learn how to do it idiomatic rather than trying to use ideas from a totally different family of programming languages (algol family) in the this new language (in the lisp family).